# Shopware backend enhance category with ExtJs

Tags: extjs, models, shopware

I'm stuck in the development of an extension for Shopware.
I want to extend the administration of categories in the correct way.

To achieve that created plugin (legacy). This plugins appends the first tab within a category.

```
//{block name="backend/category/view/tabs/settings" append}
```

This is done to add a fieldset with a dropdown. The file looks like this:

```
//{block name="backend/category/view/tabs/settings" append}
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.HaendlerbundFoobarCategories.view.category.tabs.settings', {
    override:'Shopware.apps.Category.view.category.tabs.Settings',

    getItems: function() {
        var me = this;
        var items = me.callParent(arguments);
        me.FooBar = me.getFooBarSection();
        items.push(me.FooBar);
        return items;
    },

    getFooBarSection : function()
    {
        var me = this;
        return Ext.create('Ext.form.FieldSet',{
            title: 'FooBar Verlinkung',
            anchor: '100%',
            defaults : me.defaults,
            disabled : false,
            items : me.getDropdowns()
        });
    },

    getDropdowns:function(){
        var me = this;

        return me.templateComboBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
            xtype:'combobox',
            fieldLabel: 'FooBar Product',
            store: me.fooBarProducts.load(),
            labelWidth: 155,
            valueField: 'id',
            displayField:'title',
            editable: true,
            allowBlank:true,
            name:'fbproduct'
        });
    }
});
//{/block}
```

The main problem I suspect is the store. Leaving it like this I get an JS
error *Cannot read property 'load' of undefined*. without the *.load()* there is no error, but I also can't determine if the store got loaded.

The store file itself is in **Views/backend/haendlerbund_foobar_categories/store/foo_bar_products**

and the content of the file is:

```
//{block name="backend/haendlerbund_foobar_categories/store/fooBarProducts"}
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.HaendlerbundFoobarCategories.store.fooBarProducts', {

//...
model: 'Shopware.apps.HaendlerbundFoobarCategories.model.fooBarProducts',
proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
         /**
         * Configure the url mapping for the different
         * store operations based on
         * @object
         */
        api : {
            read : '{url controller=HaendlerbundFoobarCategories action=getProducts}'
        },
        /**
         * Configure the data reader
         * @object
         */
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
});
//{/block}
```

**EDIT:**
For further context, this is the current state of the model the store references.

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.HaendlerbundFoobarCategories.model.fooBarProducts', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    /**
     * If the name of the field is 'id' extjs assumes automatically that
     * this field is an unique identifier.
     * @integer
     */
    idProperty : 'id',

    fields:[
        { name : 'id',          type: 'int' },
        { name : 'ffid',        type: 'bigint' },
        { name : 'title',       type: 'string' },
        { name : 'description', type: 'string' },
        { name : 'price',       type: 'decimal' },
        { name : 'vat',         type: 'decimal' },
        { name : 'image',       type: 'text' },
        { name : 'active',      type: 'boolean' },
        { name : 'createdAt',   type: 'datetime' },
        { name : 'modfiedAt',   type: 'datetime' }
    ],


    /*associations: [
        {
            relation: 'OneToMany',
            storeClass: 'Shopware.apps.HaendlerbundFoobarCategories.store.fooBarProducts',
            loadOnDemand: true,

            type: 'hasMany',
            model: 'Shopware.apps.HaendlerbundFooBarCategories.model.fooBarProducts',
            name: 'getCategories',
            associationKey: 'categories'
        },
    ]*/
});
```

And the php controller which the store references as well  has the following content:

```
<?php

class Shopware_Controllers_Backend_HaendlerbundFoobarCategories extends Shopware_Controllers_Backend_Application
{
    protected $model = 'Shopware\CustomModels\Product\FFProduct';
    protected $alias = 'ffproducts';

    protected function getListQuery()
    {
        $builder = parent::getListQuery();
        return $builder;
    }

    protected function getDetailQuery($id)
    {
        $builder = parent::getDetailQuery($id);
        return $builder;
    }

    protected function getAdditionalDetailData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    public function getProducts(){
        $builder = $this->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $builder->select('*')
                ->from($model, $alias);

        $data['id']     = 1;
        $data['ffid']   = 1;
        $data['title']  = 'lorem ipsum'; 

        $this->view()->assign([
            'success'   => true,
            'data'      => $data,
            'total'     => 1

        ]);

    }
}
```

It should return some dummy data for now.

I fail to solve the problem. As any documentation I was able to find was either focused on creating a separate component of changing an existing field. I suspect that I'm in the wrong scope or have a namespacing error or something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
store: somestore.load()
```

the combobox will bind to the value **returned** by `load`. The load function does not return anything, so the combo's store config is set to `undefined`.

What you want to do may be

```
    me.fooBarProducts.load();
    return me.templateComboBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        xtype:'combobox',
        fieldLabel: 'FooBar Product',
        store: me.fooBarProducts,
        labelWidth: 155,
        valueField: 'id',
        displayField:'title',
        editable: true,
        allowBlank:true,
        name:'fbproduct'
    });
```

Comment: I tested you suggestion. This does not make a difference.
But the input that maybe the store does not return any data gave me an idea to test.

Comment: Please do a `console.log(me.fooBarProducts)` and check what you get.

Comment: Will do, when I find out where to put this to actually see the response. By now I try to test the naming of the classes and so on. I guess that there is some mixed up things as well.

neither the store nor the model are in a pure ExtJS environment and I actually try to figure out if I at least got the right scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the store assigning to combobox

this line of code isn't correct:

`store: me.fooBarProducts.load(),`

Usually a store should be only connected to a combobox like this:

store:'fooBarProducts'

Heres a fiddle to show you:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1kqj

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    var yourStore=Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
        fields:[{
            name:'text'
        },{
            name:'value'
        }],
        data:[
            {text:'test1',value:'testVal1'},
            {text:'test2',value:'testVal2'},
            {text:'test3',value:'testVal3'}
            ]
    });
    Ext.create({
        xtype:'window',
        width:300,
        height:200,
        items:[{
            xtype:'combo',
            displayField:'text',
            valueField:'value',
            store:yourStore
        },{
            xtype:'combo',
            displayField:'text',
            valueField:'value',
            store:yourStore
        }]
    }).show();
}

});
```

have also a look here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html

for a combobox example 
and here to store declaration:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html

To load your store, you should call the store load out of combo declaration

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helps a bit with understanding the behavior. My experience with ExtJs is almost non existent.

I will try to combine your answer with the one from @Alexander